# heartbeat sensor for pi

Tags: pi-3b+, hardware, python-3

i want to measure the heartbeat using the pulse sensor. i connected the pulse sensor to a mcp3008 adc and the pi.
this is the code i used

```
from pulsesensor import Pulsesensor
import time
p = Pulsesensor()
p.startAsyncBPM()

try:
    while True:
        bpm = p.BPM
        if bpm > 0:
            print("BPM: %d" % bpm)
        else:
            print("No Heartbeat found")
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    p.stopAsyncBPM()
```

the problem i am facing is the values i get are like 200,240,111,201 and so on .could you help me with the code please

Comment: what's wrong with the code? ... you did not describe the problem

Comment: `i connected the pulse sensor to a mcp3008 adc and the pi.` ... what connections did you make? ... please provide a schematic diagram